# converting PCM to wav file

Tags: c, audio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fin,*fout;
    char buffer[1028];


    int readcount=0;
    short NumChannels = 1;
    short BitsPerSample = 16;
    int SamplingRate =8000;
    short numOfSamples = 160;

    int ByteRate = NumChannels*BitsPerSample*SamplingRate/8;
    short BlockAlign = NumChannels*BitsPerSample/8;
    int DataSize = NumChannels*numOfSamples *  BitsPerSample/8;
    int chunkSize = 16;
    int totalSize = 36 + DataSize;
    short audioFormat = 1;

    if((fout = fopen("sample.wav", "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening out file ");
    }

    //totOutSample = 0;
    fwrite("RIFF", sizeof(char), 4,fout);
    fwrite(&totalSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite("WAVE", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite("fmt ", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite(&chunkSize, sizeof(int),1,fout);
    fwrite(&audioFormat, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&NumChannels, sizeof(short),1,fout);
    fwrite(&SamplingRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&ByteRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&BlockAlign, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&BitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite("data", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite(&DataSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);
    fin=fopen("sample.raw","r");
    fout=fopen("sample.wav","a");

    while(!feof(fin))
    {
        fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fin);
        fputs(buffer,fout);
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem in this code. Header is proper and its even properly written on file. But whenever opening in frhed the .wav file, its showing one extra field. And also file is not playing. If I try opening the file using media info its showing properties as expected except duration

> Format                                   : Wave File size
>   : 8.29 KiB Duration                                 : 20ms Overall bit
>   rate mode                    : Constant Overall bit rate
>   : 3 394 Kbps
>
> Audio Format                                   : PCM Format settings,
>   Endianness              : Little Format settings, Sign
>   : Signed Codec ID                                 : 1 Duration
>   : 20ms Bit rate mode                            : Constant Bit rate
>   : 128 Kbps Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
>   Sampling rate                            : 8 000 Hz Bit depth
>   : 16 bits Stream size                              : 320 Bytes (4%)

Comment: Can anyone help me out by explaining what input should I give for the numofSamples which is used to calculate Subchunk2Size    (Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8)? Here  Subchunk2Size   is DataSize.

Comment: Got it. Numofsamples is equivalent to your pcm file size as those are the sample values. So find the size of the pcm file and that's your  NumSamples. I used the following code to find the size of pcm file     fin=fopen("sample.raw","r");
 if (stat ("sample.raw", & sb) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "'stat' failed for '%s': %s.\n",
                 "sample.raw", strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    numOfSamples=sb.st_size;

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about the file formats, but I find it hard to believe they would have a binary header followed by ascii data. So the use of fgets and fputs I find questionable since fgets looks for a \n terminator. So you could be losing data if the buffer fills up before it happens to find a \n ( 0xa ) byte.

```
while(!feof(fin))
{
    fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fin);
    fputs(buffer,fout);
}
```

Something like this would make more sense

```
size_t n;
while((n = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fin)) > 0) {
   if(n != fwrite(buffer, 1, n, fout)) {
      perror("fwrite");
      exit(1);
   }
}
if(n < 0) {
   perror("fread");
   exit(1);
}
```

Also, why do you close fout and then reopen it?

Comment: Yea it worked... Thanks Mr. Charlie Burns... Some more modification in Header along with ur suggestion turned my favour... Also I removed reopening the file... :) THANK YOU SO MUCHHH.... :)

Comment: @Siri may you please link to your final solution. I also had a need for this please.